# How to automatically built 3 column cards inside of a row html frontend

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4, frontend

i am new at django and i am learning html too.

So, i want to do a simple question (maybe).

I am developing a little project in django, and i have a problem with a frontend part. Especifically in a HTML part.

as you can see in the picture, i am developing a kind of a ecommerce. But i have a mistake in my HTML part. I don´t want to show the cards of the articles like a list of rows, like the image.

[image]

I want want to show 3 cards articles by columns, automatically done when i add a new article.

Just like this another picture (made from paint :P):

[image]

This is my HTML, to that part:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <h5>Tipo de vista:<button class="btn btn-lg" type="reset""><a href="{% url 'adminview:article' %}"><h6>Lista</h6></button></a>/<button class="btn btn-lg" type="reset""><a href="{% url 'adminview:cuadricula' %}"><h6>Cuadrícula</h6></button></a></button></button></h5>
    <div class="card mb-8">
      <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
      Productos disponibles</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            {% if articulo %}
            {% for articulo in articulo %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card h-100 w-100">
                <a href="article/id/{{ articulo.id }}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{% url 'home:preload_image' pk=articulo.pk %}" alt=""></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                    <hr class="sidebar-divider">
                    <a href="article/id/{{articulo.id}}">{{articulo.nombre_producto}}</a>
                  </h4>
                  <h5>{{articulo.precio}} bsS</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">{{articulo.Descripcion}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  {% if articulo.valoracion == 0 %}
                  <span class="text-warning">&#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734;</span>
                  <h6>{{articulo.id_clasificacion_fk}}</h6>
                  <h6>Sin valoración</h6>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if articulo.valoracion == 1 %}
                  <span class="text-warning">&#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734;</span>
                  <h6>{{articulo.id_clasificacion_fk}}</h6>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if articulo.valoracion == 2 %}
                  <span class="text-warning">&#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734;</span>
                  <h6>{{articulo.id_clasificacion_fk}}</h6>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if articulo.valoracion == 3 %}
                  <span class="text-warning">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734;</span>
                  <h6>{{articulo.id_clasificacion_fk}}</h6>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if articulo.valoracion == 4 %}
                  <span class="text-warning">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</span>
                  <h6>{{articulo.id_clasificacion_fk}}</h6>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if articulo.valoracion == 5 %}
                  <span class="text-warning">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</span>
                  <h6>{{articulo.id_clasificacion_fk}}</h6>
                  <h6>Artículo destacado!</h6>
                  {% endif %}
                  <a href="{% url 'article:show_article' id_article=articulo.pk %}"><img src="{% static 'img/verify.png'%}"width="40px" height="40px" /></a>
                  <a href="product/edit/{{articulo.id}}"><img src="{% static 'img/edit.png'%}"width="40px" height="40px" /></a>
                  <a href="delete_article/{{articulo.id}}"><img src="{% static 'img/delete.png'%}"width="40px" height="40px" /></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <h5>No hay artículos disponibles.</h5></div>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </table>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 mt-4 mb-3">
              <a href="{% url 'adminview:add_article' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"><img src="{% static 'img/plus.png'%}"width="20px" height="20px" />
                Añadir nuevo producto
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <canvas id="myBarChart" width="100%" height="0"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In simple words, i actually have it like the first image and i want to have it like the second.

I am using the simple bootstrap theme.

Hope you can help me!.

Comment: This is more related to bootstrap than it is to django

Comment: Sorry, i have modified the title and the tags. If you can help me i appreciate :-)

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I have the 4.2.1 version.

Comment: I see you are using dataTables? That wont be possible. You can rather display image in first column of your table, the next, price or some detail and so on. But if you can change that to using [Bootstrap Card Groups Or Card Deks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-groups) to get what you want. Why are you using dataTables if I may ask?

Comment: The problem with that is, if i have 4 articles in the page. The fourth one fills to the entire screen, and i want to stay with the same card height just like the images that i put does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192148/discussion-between-kingraphaii-and-luis-bermudez).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try adding row class to table tag

Comment: can you add a working demo of what you are proposing... that will give a lot more weight to your answer